# Set application pool in IISExpress to a specific domain user

Tags: iis-express

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to build an MVC web application, and IIS Express to host it on my local machine.  In order to access specific domain resources (SQL Integrated authentication, file systems, etc.) I have the need to configure the identity that the application pool runs as.

If I instead host it using IIS, it works as intended.

In my applicationhost.config file:

```
<system.applicationHost>
  <applicationPools>
    <add name="MyPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPiplelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true">
      <processModel indentityType="SpecificUser" userName="Domain\UserName" password="Password" />
    </add>
  </applicationPools>
  <sites>
    <site name="MySite" id="1">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="MyPool">
        ....
      </application>
    <site>
  <sites>
</system.applicationHost>
```

If I set default to run as the specified pool, it works correctly, but I can't get a specific site to run under the different app pool.

```
<applicationDefaults applicationPool="MyPool" />
```

I've seen numerous posts around the interwebs saying that the configuration I have should work, but it doesn't, so what am I missing?

Comment: Same issue here - VS2013, Windows 8. I'm suspecting this is yet another example of the infinite capacity for fail of Windows 8, because the same setup works fine under Windows 7.